# Updating an object class reference in a method?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an array containing pointers to different objects of `UIView` subclasses.

A method is referring to a random one of these objects simply as:

```
- (void)specialMethod(UIView*)target_UIView{
   …
}
```

The question is, I want to refer to the `UIView` by its subclass, depending on what it is.

I can get the `UIView` subclass name by going:

```
NSString *theClassName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [target_UIView class]];
```

**But how can I change the class reference (?) of this object, in the method, from UIView
to its actual subclass?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to use the polymorphic property:

You create your `UIView` class custom and add it your special method:

```
@interface MyUIView : UIView

- (void)specialMethod;

@end
```

Then your subviews extend `MyUIView` instead of `UIView`:

```
@interface MyViewA : MyUIView

@end
```

You override the `specialMethod` in each sub class:

```
@implementation MyViewA

- (void)specialMethod
{
    // Do something
}

@end
```

and finally, in your method:

```
- (void)specialMethod(MyUIView*)target_UIView{
   [target_UIView specialMethod];
   …
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure about what you are asking, but this method may solve your problem:

```
if ([target_UIView isMemberOfClass:[MySubClassView class]])
{
   MySubClassView *mySubclassView = (MySubClassView *)target_UIView;
}
```

You can check if that view belong to that class, and cast it.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I am trying to do, but because there are several different classes, I do not want to use if/else statements. (And new classes may be added in future.) Is there a way to do this without the if/else statements? Thanks.

Comment: I can't think in any other way than an if/else

Comment: Oh, that is a shame. :| Thanks for your response anyway.

Comment: The best way is to use the polymorphic property of OOP languages.